# How to specify a type for iterator in rust?

Tags: rust

When I try running following code

```rust
fn main(){
    let a= vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let values = a.iter().map(|_| None);
    println!("{:?}",values.len());
}
```

I get following error

> cannot infer type for type parameter `T` declared on the enum `Option`

I am not sure how can I specify the type for generic T?

Comment: Similar problem with `Result`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72708402/401059

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you have a call to `map` that always emits `None`.  The compiler can usually intuit the type for `Some(T)`, but not for `None`, since it's the same regardless of the type of the option.

In this case, the easiest way to go about it is to use the turbofish syntax on the `map` call, like so:

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let values = a.iter().map::<Option<i32>, _>(|_| None);
    println!("{:?}", values.len());
}
```

Note that in this case, we use `_` to let the compiler infer the type of the closure because it's not necessary or convenient to specify.  With this hint, the compiler is capable of determining the type of the iterator.

You could *also* explicitly specify the iterator type by giving a type for `values`, but because types of iterator chains quickly become extremely unwieldy, it's usually more convenient to use the turbofish (`::<>`) syntax on a method instead.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to annotate the type of `None` directly:

```
let values = a.iter().map(|_| None as Option<i32>);
```

or even:

```
let values = a.iter().map(|_| None::<i32>);
```

Comment: Or `None::<i32>`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman nice! I didn't know that was a thing